# CreateJS play a child movieclip

Tags: movieclip, createjs, timeline

If you have a child movieclip on stage with an animation in it, can you have the main timeline play the child movieclip at a certain timeline?

mc_child is a 20 frame animation with this.stop() at frame one so that it is paused at the beginning.

If you add the code this.mc_child.play() or this.mc_child.gotoAndPlay(5) you get an error in createJS. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined."

How do you make child movieclips play at a certain frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gotoAndPlay(5);`

Have a look at the EaselJS documentation:
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html

Comment: Thanks, a lot, Grant. You are the, Man! Thanks for your amazing work and taking time to comment. At RPA in Santa Monica, we are using createJS now. 
Here is the weird thing. The gotoAndPlay and play() commands are working as of 8/4/15. Last week, using the CDN link I was getting that "No play() property" around 7/24 - 7/31. Using http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.1.min.js. Weird.

Comment: No problem. Glad you're liking EaselJS, and would love to see what you're building with it. Nothing has changed on the CDN since we posted 0.8.1 in May. Weird.

Comment: OK, Flash CC spits easeljs-0.7.1.min.js. I will be sure to manually update it to 8.1. Thanks!